# Как разобраться с chart js?

Tags: javascript, css, graphics, chart.js

Есть пара вопросов, с которыми никак не могу разобраться -

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Длинный заголовок", "Blue", "Длинный заголовок", "Green", "Длинный заголовок", "Orange","Длинный заголовок", "Blue", "Длинный заголовок", "Green", "заголовок", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
           fontColor: 'green',
          },
         }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
```

1) Снизу подписи начинают идти через 1(происходит это из-за длинного описания), можно ли насильно заставить, чтоб выводились все описания? 
- Знаю способ, что можно размер шрифта уменьшить, но чтобы вывести все, там он очень маленький получается, интересуют еще способы в общем

2) Можно ли первой подписи данный к примеру красный цвет, а остальным уже зеленый ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: 'green',                  
                            autoSkip:false,                  
                            },
                    }]
```

[Tick Configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration)